# How to connect a minimum variance portfolio to the Two Fund Theorem using Lagrange?

Tags: recreational-mathematics, finance

I've received this question for my Mathematics course at school, and I'm completely stumped as to how we should approach it. I'm unsure how to use the information about a minimum variance portfolio, and use it to make a conclusion about the theorem in the question. Any help would be appreciated!

[image]

Comment: You need to specify "two fund theorem".

Comment: any portfolio on efficient frontier is a linear combination of C^(-1)*μ and C^(-1)*(the 1 vector) for C being covariance of the two funds. Basically the entire efficient portfolio can be generated from two portfolios (funds)